# Failed to transform jar to match attributes

Tags: android, android-jetifier

```
Execution failed for task ':app:checkClassicGooglePlayDebugDuplicateClasses'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:classicGooglePlayDebugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Failed to transform SaaS_TalkingDataSDK_Android_V5.0.0.jar to match attributes {artifactType=enumerated-runtime-classes, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for EnumerateClassesTransform: /home/circleci/project/app/libs/SaaS_TalkingDataSDK_Android_V5.0.0.jar.
         > zip END header not found
```

I am getting this error in Android project which has following configurations

`build:gradle:7.0.4`

And `android.useAndroidX=true android.enableJetifier=true` in `gradle.properties`

Comment: Can you share the build.gradle files?

Comment: It sounds like this issue -> https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/195441712

Comment: @virengujariya were you able to fix this issue

Answer (score 5):

use jdk 17 it's solve my problem

Comment: Thank you very much!!! I spent 3 days trying to resolve this. I searched many sites and nothing was helpful. Thank you, again!

Answer (score 3):

If it happens locally, just delete the corrupted cache and restart Android Studio (or IntelliJ IDEA). Cache location for Gradle is in `~/.gradle`.

If you want to clear cache in Circle CI, refer to this article: [Clear project dependency cache](https://support.circleci.com/hc/en-us/articles/115015426888-Clear-project-dependency-cache)

Source: [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52411697/1429387).

Answer (score 1):

Turned out that TalkingDataSDK jar was big in size so we had to install `git lfs` on CI to fix the issue.