# Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDexDebug' using Cloud Firestore and Supabase

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, supabase, supabase-flutter

I was trying to use Cloud Firestore in my project, and it gave me this error. So, I tried to switch to Supabase service, and it continues to give the same error.

My pubspec.yaml

```yaml
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  supabase_flutter: ^2.3.1
```

My android/app/build.gradle

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.aumigos_da_vizinhanca"
    minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion
    targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
    versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
    versionName flutterVersionName
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

This is the error's text:

```
ERROR:C:\MINHAS COISAS SSD\FLUTTER\aumigos_da_vizinhanca\build\path_provider_android\intermediates\runtime_library_classes_jar\debug\classes.jar: D8: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "String.length()" because "<parameter1>" is null
ERROR:C:\MINHAS COISAS SSD\FLUTTER\aumigos_da_vizinhanca\build\url_launcher_android\intermediates\runtime_library_classes_jar\debug\classes.jar: D8: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "String.length()" because "<parameter1>" is null

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDexDebug'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Failed to transform classes.jar (project :url_launcher_android) to match attributes {artifactType=android-dex, asm-transformed-variant=NONE, com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr=7.3.0, com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr=debug, com.android.build.gradle.internal.attributes.VariantAttr=debug, dexing-enable-desugaring=true, dexing-enable-jacoco-instrumentation=false, dexing-is-debuggable=true, dexing-min-sdk=19, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for DexingWithClasspathTransform: C:\MINHAS COISAS SSD\FLUTTER\aumigos_da_vizinhanca\build\url_launcher_android\intermediates\runtime_library_classes_jar\debug\classes.jar.
         > Error while dexing.

> Failed to transform classes.jar (project :path_provider_android) to match attributes {artifactType=android-dex, asm-transformed-variant=NONE, com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr=7.3.0, com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr=debug, com.android.build.gradle.internal.attributes.VariantAttr=debug, dexing-enable-desugaring=true, dexing-enable-jacoco-instrumentation=false, dexing-is-debuggable=true, dexing-min-sdk=19, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for DexingWithClasspathTransform: C:\MINHAS COISAS SSD\FLUTTER\aumigos_da_vizinhanca\build\path_provider_android\intermediates\runtime_library_classes_jar\debug\classes.jar.
         > Error while dexing.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 17s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

NOTE: I also try to put this code line in android/app/build.gradle, but it didn't work.

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:2.0.1'
}
```

What can I do now?

Comment: Have you tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/70848832/13625293